# Is my image too low res for semantic segmentation task?

Tags: dataset, image-segmentation, labels, semantic-segmentation, labeling

I am trying to solve a semantic segmentation task in the field of agriculture and I have some ortophoto drone images that have been acquired at the same height above the crops and in different vegetation stages of the crops. Right now I am trying to label the images in GIMP by marking all the pixels that cover crops in all the pictures and after trying to do this for the second day now I'm starting to think the images are not sufficiently detailed because it's hard for me to distinguish between pixels that are and aren't overlapping the crops in the field. (Either that or I just don't have enough labeling experience in which case I'm hoping someone here could share their piece of advice on this) I'm thinking if I have a hard time distinguishing between crop/no-crop it must be even more difficult for a segmentation model to do that. I've attached some images examples from my dataset and for reference an image from the Vainhingen ISPRS dataset zoomed at the same level to show a comparison between object detail level. Note the same zoom level between the 2 images and the level of detail of the yellow car in the Veinhingen dataset image. I would expect to see a similar detail level in my images to make the labeling effort worthwhile. What do you think?

[image: Veinhingen Image vs Field Image with Vegetation Stage 2]
[image: Veinhingen Image vs Field Image with Vegetation Stage 3]

Comment: Hi Vlad, welcome to the Data Science Stack Exchange. In regards to your question about accurately labelling images: I would say if you cannot identify whether a certain part of the image is crop or not, how would the model do any better? At the end of the day, models are there to reflect patterns we identify. Therefore, I would not stress to much on the labelling to that level of detail.

Comment: Hi, thank you! Then I guess I only have a couple of options here:
1. Build a preprocessing pipeline that can help enhance these details in the images I have (any recommendations on this from more experienced people is welcome)
2. Annotate these images the best I can and see how well the model does
3. Collect new images where this issue doesn't occur anymore.
Any other suggestions?